# Have trouble uninstall scipy on osx

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, numpy

I've faced this specific trouble with multi-version python as 2.7 and 3.4.
python2.7 was installed by apple itself and I installed 3.4 myself and it works just fine.
When i use pip to install sklearn series(scikit-learn numpy scipy), since this pip was bound to python3.4 so python2.7 couldnt use it, and my project needs 2.7 this time. 
I'm not going to uninstall 3.4.

```
sh-3.2# python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

this means my default version of python is 2.7

My Question is when i use `pip install` & uninstall just with pip, the extras in python3.4 works fine.

And to install numpy and scipy to python2.7 I download those package and find those setup.py and run them with sudo python setup.py install. 
The numpy seems fine but the scipy have this trouble as

```
error: Command "/usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -arch x86_64 -fPIC -I/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.12.0.dev0_d69c147-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/numpy/core/include -c -c scipy/integrate/mach/d1mach.f -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/scipy/integrate/mach/d1mach.o" failed with exit status 1
```

I run this "`sudo python setup.py install`" under scipy when i didnt have gfortran(of course i failed and find out that i need one). And after get gfortran im stuck with this annoying error. 

my plan is uninstall scipy with pip first but i cant as im facing this

```
$ pip2.7 uninstall scipy
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (scipy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
Uninstalling scipy-0.13.0b1:



/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy-0.13.0b1-py2.7.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? y
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 76, in run
    requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 336, in uninstall
    req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/8k/7_gm8zxx0zlg0nx4r5dg4rz00000gn/T/pip-hA6VUE-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy-0.13.0b1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Im very frustrated but still working on it. and seeking for help.
Im not an english speaker.so sorry for my poor english.

UPDATE:just with this problem and ive fix all others like pandas or sklearn

```
sudo pip2.7 install numpy --upgrade
The directory '/Users/ink/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/ink/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.11.0-cp27-cp27m-<br>macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (3.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.9MB 275kB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 736, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-gJ8Ao6-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Answer (score 0):

Install brew

```
http://brew.sh/
```

Then follow this recipe..

https://penandpants.com/2013/04/04/install-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/python:$PATH

brew install python
brew tap homebrew/science

brew install gfortran
brew install numpy --with-openblas
brew install scipy --with-openblas
brew install matplotlib
brew install zeromq

pip install ipython
pip install pandas
pip install sklearn
```

Comment: I think ive managed with all the others but the numpy. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
aptitude purge python-numpy
```

Try this one

Comment: why do i need aptitude?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue that was resolved by reinstalling python https://www.python.org/downloads/