# Issue when importin pandas library for python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm just getting started in python and I'm currently having a issue when trying to import pandas. Below is the error i'm getting. Any help will be well appreciated.

```
return (matplotlib.__version__ >= LooseVersion('1.5') or
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Comment: do you maybe have a file called `matplotlib.py` in your current working directory?

Comment: not sure do you know how can i check that?

Comment: have you created a file called `matplotlib.py`? If so, *rename it*.

Comment: How you starting python so you can  import pandas?

Comment: i dont believe i created such file. I used homebrew to intall numpy, matplotli, scipy

Comment: Hi Merlin, after executing the import panda statement i get the above error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741131/have-trouble-uninstall-scipy-on-osx/37741786#37741786  look at link..

Comment: just solved the issue, i forgot to link myplotlib after i installed it